# Multiple tables vs rows for timescaledb / postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, timescaledb

I am designing a postgresql/timescale database where I will be recording trades on multiple stocks. For each stock I will be saving the following columns: Trade time, Attribute 1, Attribute 2, Attribute 3

As far as I can tell I have 2 options of saving this data:

1. Creating 1 table for each Stock
2. Using 1 giant table and adding a column with the Stock ID

I will frequently need to access information across time for single stocks but also often for all stocks at once. Which is the better solution for me to choose here.

Comment: you can take alook why option 1 will cause more troubles https://de.slideshare.net/hansjurgenschonig/postgresql-joining-1-million-tables

Comment: @nbk this is very interesting. In this example they attempt to join 1 Million tables. At what number of tables does this become a problem. Is solution 2 also preferable when we assume only a small amount of tables? If not then where is the tipping point?

Comment: The problem (from the slideshare) appears to be that the performance decrease with the no. of tables is **not** linear with the number of tables - in (about) slide 7, performance goes from n = 400, t = 4.7ms to n = 800, t = 18.9 ms - an increase of ~ 4 times for a doubling of the number of tables. I would expect this non-linearity to get worse with increasing numbers... but run the tests.

Comment: **Generally** speaking, if you are running into db server limits, it's your **design** that's the problem and **not** the server! A table with 1000's of stocks and a million trades each with, say, 10 - 15 attributes/per trade will be no problem on a properly indexed table!

Comment: from 64 tables up, you will get a problem, that can be solved but still. the huge table is always preferable, but still you will need a lot of hardware power in any case. eventually when you only compare small numbers of stocks, you could think about partitioning, but that will still not solve anything. the general cpnsensus is in favor a one table, which makes the queries manageble.

Comment: Similar questions were asked few itimes in https://timescale.slack.com. I suggest to check there. Both approaches are possible and have pros and cons. For example, Promscale creates [separate hypertable for each metric](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e3mAN3eHUpQ2JHDvnmkmn_9rFyqyYisIgdtgd3D1MHA/edit#). There is short discussion of this question (wide vs narrow model) in [TimescaleDB docs](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/introduction/data-model).